# .each() to toggle class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript .each() function which check the value of my div tag and toggle a css class. I am just checking the value fetched from my db and giving the a particular color.

```
$(".c").each(function() {
     if ($(this).text() < 4) {
           $(".col").toggleClass("yellow");
     } else if ($(this).text() >= 4 && $(this).text() <=6) {
           $(".col").toggleClass("orange");
     } else if ($(this).text() >= 6 && $(this).text() <=10) {
           $(".col").toggleClass("red");
     }
});
```

The problem is when I ran the code only the last else if which is the toggleClass("red') runs. And I am only getting one color which in this case is red displayed,don't know why.

My HTML is looped in a php foreach loop:

```
 <div class="col">
       <h4 class="c">'.$marks.'</h4>
       <h6>Marks</h6>
 </div> 
 <div class="col">
       <h4 class="c">'.$highest.'</h4>
       <h6>Highest</h6>
 </div>
```

[image]

Like thhe above image I was looking to put my text and number in a same color

Comment: `$(this).closest('.col').toggleClass(...)`  I'm assuming you only want to toggle the col that is the parent of the c.  `$('.col')` is a global lookup and will change them all.

Comment: yes, just like in stack overflow we have  answer column for each question. Which turns green when answered. That element contains both the number and text "submittion".I also want to include my H6 into the Color element

Comment: @Taplar is correct, and additionally .text() is returning the text as a string, and you are comparing it to integers. Even if your string contains a number, the comparison is not going to be what you want. Try using parseInt, i.e. parseInt('5') returns 5 the number.

Comment: @the_hobbes Using a comparison operator against a number forces a conversion of the other operand to a number.

Comment: Also small logical side note, if the first if is false, you know in the first else if that >= 4 will be true.  And like wise for the next else if it will be >= 6, so you could reduce those conditionals a little

Comment: @ScottMarcus true but not if there are any non-numeric characters included. '5a' > 3 is false, parseInt('5a') > 3 is true. However you're right in terms of his current markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sets the class on all the `.col` elements. to isolate just the one you are matching, you need to use **[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to look for the closest ancestor that matches your criteria.

```js
$(".c").each(function() {
  if($(this).text() < 4){
    $(this).closest($(".col")).toggleClass("yellow");
  } else if ($(this).text() >= 4 && $(this).text() <=6){
    $(this).closest($(".col")).toggleClass("orange");
  } else if ($(this).text() >= 6 && $(this).text() <=10){
    $(this).closest($(".col")).toggleClass("red");
  }
});
```

```css
.col { width: 5em; text-align:center; padding:1em; margin:5px; float:left; }
.yellow { background-color:yellow; }
.orange { background-color:orange; }
.red { background-color:red; }
h4, h6 { margin:0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
       <h4 class="c">4</h4>
       <h6>Marks</h6>
 </div> 
 <div class="col">
       <h4 class="c">7</h4>
       <h6>Highest</h6>
 </div>
 <div class="col">
       <h4 class="c">2</h4>
       <h6>Highest</h6>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting all .col elements. Change to this:

```js
$(".c").each(function() {
     if($(this).text() < 4){
           $(this).parent().toggleClass("blue");
     } else if ($(this).text() >= 4 && $(this).text() <=6) {
           $(this).parent().toggleClass("orange");
     } else if ($(this).text() >= 6 && $(this).text() <=10) {
           $(this).parent().toggleClass("red");
     }
});
```

```css
.red {
    color: red;
}
  
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
  
.orange {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
       <h4 class="c">2</h4>
       <h6>Marks</h6>
 </div> 
 <div class="col">
       <h4 class="c">5</h4>
       <h6>Highest</h6>
 </div>
```

I used blue color so to make the difference more visible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But , I was looking for the whole div to be of the same color and include the H6 tag in the same color

Comment: Just add .parent(). Edited the answer.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you that's what I was looking for. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: OK. If it was helpful, please accept/upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try the below script:

```
$("div.col h4.c").each(function() {
     if($(this).text() < 4){
           $("div.col").toggleClass("yellow");
}
     else if ($(this).text() >= 4 && $(this).text() <=6){
           $("div.col").toggleClass("orange");
}
     else if ($(this).text() >= 6 && $(this).text() <=10){
           $("div.col").toggleClass("red");
}

});
```

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow should explain what the problem was and how your code solves it. It should not just be a post of code that works. Additionally, your solution doesn't solve the problem. It would do exactly the same thing that is happening to the OP already.